# License template mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database, datamodel, inventory-management

I have to develop a software inventory (with php and mysql) and i´m planning the data model/design. The problem is that every software supplier has a different license type, with different field so it´s not as simple as creating a "licenses" table.

My best solution till now is create a "licenses" table and a "templates" table where each has about 10 columns named from 1 to 10. The license table holds the data and the templates table holds the column o field name for that data.

Is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: If you dont need to run queries on this data, you can just serialize it and dump it in a single "data" varchar field

Comment: It would probably work, though i´m interested in a solution that works with queries and is more normalized. This is part of a larger database and you never know what you will need further on :)

Comment: Have thought about a table with different types for each row that defines the type of license and so the specific template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If serializtion is not an option, then another option would be a key value design:

```
Table: LicenceAttributes

LicenceID | FieldName     | FieldValue
1         | numberofusers | 5
1         | cost          | 999
2         | somethingelse | blah
```

Like serialization, this is only a sutable design if the fields are genuinly different accross all licences.

Comment: I think thats the way to go, after reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Are yes, `EAV` thats the description i was searching my brain for!

Comment: here´s more discussion: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15199/inventory-database-structure-when-inventory-items-have-varying-attributes